# Disabling JSHint indentation check only for a specific file

Tags: javascript, indentation, jshint

I use jshint with the indent enforcing option enabled and set to 4, and would like to keep it that way for most files in the codebase.

In one specific file though, I would like to disable this check.

I tried adding the jshint comment at the top but that didn't work:

```
/* jshint indent: false */
```

This is too bad because this syntax works for other options. For example, I can disable the camelcase enforcing option with the following:

```
/* jshint camelcase: false */
```

How can I do this?

Some answers suggest that indent automatically enables the white option, but I tried the following and it didn't work either:

```
/* jshint white: false */
```

Comment: When I played around with it on their site it indicated that it expects a small integer for the indent input.  So my guess is that there is no way to override a default.  You may want to open an issue on their github page:  https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues

Comment: of course if you just want to specify a different specific indentation for that page, you can always set that directly. Just doesn't seem to be a way to ignore it completely.  Depending on what plugin/command line tool you're using, you may also be able to get JSHint to ignore the file completely or reference a different configuration file for this file.

Comment: Yes that is also what I saw, jshint was expecting an int after indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible. JSHint validates the value of the `indent` option as follows:

```
if (typeof val !== "number" || !isFinite(val) || val <= 0 || Math.floor(val) !== val) {
    error("E032", nt, g[1].trim());
    return;
}
```

As you've noticed in the comments on your question, this will raise an error if the value is not an integer greater than 0. It doesn't actually put a maximum limit on that integer though.

Depending on how you are running JSHint it may be possible to override your default configuration for files that don't care about indentation. For example, with the [JSHint Grunt task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) you can do this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        options: {
            /* Don't set indent here */
        },
        uses_defaults: ["somefile.js"],
        with_overrides: {
            options: {
                indent: 4
            },
            files: {
                src: ["someotherfile.js"]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Update**

I have [opened a pull request](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/989) with a suggested fix for this issue, so keep an eye on that and we will see if this functionality is something the JSHint team want to add.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Yes, this is fixed as of JSHint 2.0.0.